# Analysis of a linear-time algorithm for longest palindromic substring

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

#### Background

$\newcommand\ldotd{\mathinner{..}}$Last month, I heard about a new linear-time algorithm to determine the [longest palindromic substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring) called Jeuring's algorithm. It seemed interesting, therefore I had a try to analyze the algorithm. It's not too difficult to show that it's an $\Theta(n)$-time-algorithm, but I want to observe more closely.

I wrote a C++ implementation, and an essay to prove and analyze the algorithm. It's somewhat long, therefore I will only post the critical part of the code, where you can learn the algorithm by heart, see the succeeding section. You can get all my previous work from [github](https://github.com/FrankEular/pldrm). pldrm.nw is the literate programming source file, which produces the pldrm.cc and pldrm.pdf. pldrm.pdf is the essay I've written.

#### Problem

Let $A=$ the number of times *goto* statement is executed in *move loop*, and $B=$ the number of times *move loop* is executed where *goto* statement is **NOT** executed, $C=$ the number of times a[++j]=min(a[p],l) is executed in *move loop*. You can see the code in the following section.
I found that $A+B+C=2n$ and $B=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}[b_k=1]$, where $b_k$ is the length of longest tail palindrome of $s[0\ldotd k]$, and $[P]$ is [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). For details, you can read my pdf from [github](https://github.com/FrankEular/pldrm).
I'm looking for somebody to help me analyze the quantity $A,C$. Any help? Thanks!

#### The critical part of the algorithm

Given that $s[1\ldotd n]$ is the string inputted, and $n$ is the length of $s$, where $s[0]=1,s[n+1]=0$.
We say $l+r$ is the center of substring $s[l\ldotd r]$. For example, $4$ is the center of $s[2\ldotd2]$ or $s[1\ldotd3]$.
$a_k$ is the length of the longest palindrome whose center is $k$, and $a[0\ldotd2n]$ is the array to save $\langle a_k\rangle$.
**The algorithm is used to determine $a_k$.**
We call some string $A$ is a tail palindrome of the other string $B$ if and only if $A$ is a palindromic tail substring of $B$. For example, $A=aba$ and $B=aaaababa$, where $A$ is palindromic and $A$ is a tail substring of $B$.

Here's the critical part of the code:

```
<<main loop>>=
j = 1;
l = 1;
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 0;
for (int k=2; k<=n+1; k++) {
  <<process>>
  advance:
  ;
}
@
```

Process is made up of an infinite loop, which is used to find the longest tail palindrome of $s[0\ldotd k]$. There are two exits of it. One is in extension subroutine, while the other one is in move loop. The way of exit is *goto advance;*.

```
<<process>>=
for (;;) {
  <<check>>
  <<move loop>>
}
@
```

The check subroutine checks whether a tail palindrome of $s[0\ldotd k-1]$ could be extended to that of $s[0\ldotd k]$. If so, exit from the process loop and advance $k$, otherwise start the move loop.

```
<<check>>=
if (s[k] == s[k-l-1]) {
  l += 2;
  goto advance;
}
@
```

Here's the move loop, which looks short and easy. It's used to find a shorter tail palindrome of $s[0\ldotd k-1]$.

```
<<move loop>>=
a[++j] = l;
for (p=j-1; --l>=0&&l!=a[p]; p--) {
  a[++j] = min(a[p], l);
}
if (l < 0) {
  l = 1;
  goto advance;
}
@
```

Comment: Even if looking at your pdf-file, it's hard to understand what is going on. I think your question should be more self-contained and direct: what exactly does the algorithm look like? With some pseudocode then, where's the hard part?

Comment: @Juho I restructed my post so that you can see my problem explicitly. To your disappointment, I have no psuedo code. I thought the C++ code and the comments around code is readable, therefore I pasted the critical part of my code in the main post. Thanks!

Comment: Pseudocode is generally easier to grasp and therefore to analyse. Also, it would be useful if you defined $A$ and $C$ completely here, for links may break.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks. the definition of $A,B,C$ are stated here. $B$ is somewhat hard to describe.